# How to set input shape of LSTM for sentence level embedding

Tags: python, keras, lstm, embedding, sentence

I am working with LSTM with sentence level embedding. I have review text where I set the max length sentence of review=58 and convert the each sentence in the review to embedding with 1024 dimension. After converting all the sentence in the review I got 58*1024=59392 dimension of array for each review.
My data consist of 1430 review.

The shape of data is
X.shape
(1430,59392)
Y.shape
(1430,)

Here is my model for the LSTM

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],58,1024)
x_test=x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0],58,1024)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(58, 1024)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32)


y_pred= model.predict_classes(x_test)
f1= f1_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

However, I got error for calculate the f1_score
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and unknown targets

when I check my y_pred.shape it is (286,58,1) and my y_test.shape (268,1)

Could anyone help please?